# Not able to spy the menu item in Application Moduler for web application after highlighting the Menu item

Tags: blueprism

I would like to spy on the menu items for the web application in blue prism but I'm unable to do so.

When I try to spy on the application I'm getting the below error.

> Error - Highlighting results - No elements match the supplied query
>   terms

I'm trying to spy as a normal web element. Can anyone provide me with a proper solutions for these kind of scenarios?

I tried all the options but I'm still not able to spy on the object.

Comment: Without more information, nobody can help you adequately. Is it a flash-based appplication? Java-based web applicaiton? Have you read the Blue Prism Browser Automation Guide? What version of Blue Prism are you using? What spy modes have you tried? Does that error show up when you attempt to control-click on the element, or when you try to reference it using a navigation/read/write/etc. stage?

Comment: i am using version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are attaching to the correct window. If not you will get this error.

Comment: How to work on Mouse over action in HTML Mode for Web application